# Why do my image gets cropped when resized in browser?

Tags: html, css

When height is reduced below certain limit the image placed at top of div is not visible and cannot be scrolled up as shown in the pictures. Can anyone tell on how to solve this.

Webpage when resized:
[image: Webpage when resized]

Full webpage:
[image: Full webpage]

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
}
.box {
  background: lightblue;
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  min-height: 300px;
}
img {
  position: relative;
  top: -20px;
  left: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">   
  <img id="xy"src="https://placeimg.com/50/50/animals">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At "body" part of css, try "min-height" instead of "height".

```css
    /*your code*/
    
body{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
    align-items: center;
}
.box{
    background: lightblue;
    width: 300px;
    height: 500px;
    min-height: 300px;
}
    
    /*try this one instead ("min-height" instead of "height") and (added "margin-top: 5vh" to ".box")*/
    
        body{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        min-height: 100vh;
        align-items: center;
    }

 
        .box{
        margin-top: 5vh;
        background: lightblue;
        width: 300px;
        height: 500px;
        min-height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Even if I add min-height some part of the image is being cropped after resizing.

Comment: add ".box" section of css "margin-top: 5vh".

Comment: Thank you It somewhat works. I have added @media screen so that after some height margin-top will come to effect and div will be at centre of web-page

Answer (score 0):

Your `img` is positioned `relative` to the *nearest positioned ancestor*. That means it is being placed -10px beneath the body, because `.box` does not have any `position` set.